# Force leading zeros in echo of base conversion

Tags: sed, echo, conversion

i'm trying to obtain a sequence in ternary values organised like that :

```
0 0 0 0 1    
0 0 0 0 2    
0 0 0 1 0    
0 0 0 1 1  
.........  
.........  
2 2 2 2 2
```

for that i use :

```
 for i in `seq 001 242`  
 do echo  'obase=3; '$i'' | bc | sed  's/\(.\{1\}\)/\1 /g'  
 done
```

but i obtain

```
1  
2  
1 0  
1 1  
....  
2 2 2 2 2
```

How can i force echo of the missing 0 in the result as they are important to use as another script parameters  ?

Comment: Use `printf` with a format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `printf` to format the numbers:

```
for i in $( seq 1 242 ) ; do
    printf '%05d\n' $( bc <<< 'obase=3; '$i )
done | sed  's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

Also, no need to put empty string after `$i`, and no need to quantify `{1}` in the regex.

It might be faster to use brace expansion in zsh, ksh93, bash or `yash -o braceexpand`:

```
printf '%s\n' {0..2}\ {0..2}\ {0..2}\ {0..2}\ {0..2}
```

Comment: Thank you very very much , you made my day ! effectively brace expansion is way much faster .

Answer (score 1):

The loop isn't really necessary, so I'd do it like this:

```
( echo "obase=3"; seq 1 242 ) |
    bc |
    sed -e 's!^!00000!' -e 's!^0*\(.....\)$!\1!' -e 's!.!& !g'
```

What this does is to add five zeros to the left side, and then take the rightmost five digits, separating each one from the next with a space.

Answer (score 0):

With `zsh` or `ksh93`, you can also do:

```
typeset -i3 i
for ((i = 1; i <= 242; i++)) { printf '%05d\n' "${i#*#}"; }
```

With  `ksh93`:

```
printf '%05..3d\n' {1..242}
```

With `zsh`:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 242; i++)) printf '%05d\n' $(([##3]i))
```

Pipe them all to `sed 's/./& /;s/ $//'` (or `sed 's/./ &/2g'` with GNU `sed`) to insert spaces in between the digits. Or with `zsh`:

```
for ((i = 0; i <= 242; i++)) print ${(s::)${(l:5::0:)$(([##3]i))}}
```